# What is the book given to Jesus?

Tags: quran, prophet-isa, ahlul-kitab

I was watching a wonderful talk by Mufti Menk (no longer on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5vcVn6tUFk)) and at around the 25 min mark, he explains (and I know this is in the Quran also) that when the prophet Jesus spoke, he said that he has been given the book.

I thought it was only our Prophet Muhammad (S.A.W - may peace be upon him) that had the book sent down to him in the time of Ramadan?

Can someone clarify?

Comment: I think this us obvious or why do we call Jews and Christians poeple of the book?

Comment: sorry, you are correct. I guess I got my wires crossed when Mufti Menk said this. The book in this context would have been the bible? Is that correct? At this point Islam was not established, correct?

Comment: Taurat (Musa), Zabur (Dawud), Injil (Isa), Quran (Muhammad) are the books accepted as revelation in islam.

Answer (score 2):

This is referring to the [*Gospel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_in_Islam) (or *Injil*) which was revealed to Prophet Isa (Jesus).

> **Then We sent following their footsteps Our messengers and followed [them] with Jesus, the son of Mary, and gave him the Gospel.** And We placed in the hearts of those who followed him compassion and mercy and monasticism, which they innovated; We did not prescribe it for them except [that they did so] seeking the approval of Allah . But they did not observe it with due observance. So We gave the ones who believed among them their reward, but many of them are defiantly disobedient.
>   <sub>[Qur'an 57:27](https://quran.com/57/27)</sub>

The Gospel is thought to have been corrupted from its original form and became the Bible of today.  See [Why does Islam reject the current versions of the Bible and Torah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/43508/17163)